# R last observation for milliseconds

Tags: r, xts, milliseconds, endpoints

I have `xts` objects for daily trades and quotes for five years with a time stamp of the index containing milliseconds. I need to group rows which have same seconds time stamp and the same milliseconds. I can use a loop, but in this case it works enormously long. I'm trying to use endpoints function, but it doesn't work. Here is an example:

```
testData <- as.xts( 1:4, order.by = c(as.POSIXct("2009-09-30 10:00:00.543", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC"), as.POSIXct("2009-09-30 10:00:00.545", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC"),as.POSIXct("2009-09-30 10:00:01.543", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC"),as.POSIXct("2009-09-30 10:00:01.543", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC")))

                       [,1]
2009-09-30 23:00:00.542    1
2009-09-30 23:00:00.545    2
2009-09-30 23:00:01.542    3
2009-09-30 23:00:01.542    4

endpoints(testData, on = "us")

[1] 0 4
```

But I expect it to return

```
[1] 0 1 2 4
```

So time with different milliseconds are considered different. 
How can I do thit, please help me!

Comment: What is your operating system? *Subsecond on periods are not supported on Windows.*,Read `?endpoints`. It is working as expected on Mac.

Comment: Psidom, yes, you're right, thank you. I'm using Windows, but what should I do then, I can't use loop.

Comment: On a mac it returns `#[1] 0 1 2 4`. Looking at the code for endpoints I see that I also get that result from `.Call("endpoints", .index(testData)%/%1e-06, 1L, 1, TRUE,  PACKAGE = "xts")`

Comment: I see, so then I'm just trapped using **xts** type objects in R. Thank you anyway.